# Issues with jQuery queue/dequeue…

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, queue, deque

I have written a function using jQuery queue/dequeue that isn’t working properly, but I can’t figure out why. Take a look here:

http://codepen.io/ProfessorSamoff/pen/XbVRKg

If you look at the end of the function, there’s a part that’s commented out:

```
/*$('.msg').delay(2000, 'timer').queue('timer', function(){ 
 $(this).empty().fadeIn(5).append('GO!');
}).dequeue('timer');*/
```

With this commented out, the script runs fine, counting down from 3 to 1 using the fadeIn() functions, etc. But when I uncomment the last part, the function begins counting from 2 instead of 3 and the fadeIn() timing is off.

What am I missing here? is it a lame mistake or something inherently wrong with the queue/dequeue functionality?

```js
/*var go = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 500;
console.log(go);*/

$('.start').click(function() {
   $('.start').remove();
   $('.msg').delay(2000, 'timer').queue('timer', function(){ 
     $(this).empty().fadeIn(200).append('3').delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
   }).dequeue('timer');

   $('.msg').delay(2000, 'timer').queue('timer', function(){ 
      $(this).empty().fadeIn(200).append('2').delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
   }).dequeue('timer');

   $('.msg').delay(2000, 'timer').queue('timer', function(){ 
     $(this).empty().fadeIn(200).append('1').delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
   }).dequeue('timer');
   
/*$('.msg').delay(2000, 'timer').queue('timer', function(){ 
     $(this).empty().fadeIn(5).append('GO!');
   }).dequeue('timer');*/
});
```

```css
body {
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
   margin: 3em;
}
.start {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 1em 2em 0.8em 1.9em;
   font-weight: bold;
   background: limegreen;
   border: 1px solid #777;
   border-radius: 10px;
}
.start:hover {
   background: lightgreen;
}
.msg {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 3em;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="start">Start</button>
<p class="msg"></p>
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not just a link to codepen.

Comment: The code in the commented-out function is equivalent to $(this).text('GO!').fadeIn(5) which I suspect isn't what you meant.

Comment: I am trying to create the simplest way to countdown from 3 (3-2-1) within one HTML element and then end with the word, "GO!"

Comment: Why not use `setTimeout()`?

Comment: This is my third attempt at making something brutally simple (I’m a teacher). The first version used setInterval() in two different ways:

http://codepen.io/ProfessorSamoff/pen/qdVzMd

http://codepen.io/ProfessorSamoff/pen/xGpdZP

I haven’t yet tried setTimeout().

What I’d really like to know is, why isn’t THIS way working?

Comment: i dont know if im wrong but in every example i've seen, dequeue is inside the function of queueu

Comment: That tends to break this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/*var go = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 500;
console.log(go);*/

$('.start').click(function() {

   $('.start').remove();
   $('.msg').delay(2000, 'timer').queue('timer', function(next){ 
     $(this).empty().fadeIn(200).append('3').delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
     next();
   })

   $('.msg').delay(2000, 'timer').queue('timer', function(next){ 
      $(this).empty().fadeIn(200).append('2').delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
      next();
   })

   $('.msg').delay(2000, 'timer').queue('timer', function(next){ 
     $(this).empty().fadeIn(200).append('1').delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
     next();
   })

$('.msg').delay(2000, 'timer').queue('timer', function(next){ 
     $(this).empty().fadeIn(5).append('GO!');
       next();
   })

.dequeue( 'timer' );
});
```

Try this one here

Comment: Yes! Thank you… I totally get that too, which is really helpful.